# Exhaustion of skeletal muscle and ligaments

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, muscles, bone-biology

I read somewhere that while doing lifting back should be straight(means normal curve), so that erectors muscle in back do the work but it gets tired easily. Hence we form curve on our back like when we sit on chair our back curves and this curve put stress on ligaments of spine which is harmful. 
[image] Since ligaments dont get tired we feel curved back as easier. Does ligament have any mechanism ti get tired like lactic acid in muscles?